# Failed to insert one column data into the wampserver by using php script

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I am tried to insert the values into my wampserver, I succeed to insert name column and email column but it is not possible to insert pass word field into the database please check what I done mistake here.
[image]

above image gives you a clear idea, how that pass word field looks, note that that password field i tried to save the data in VARCHAR() but not save the data please check my below php and html codes
**init.php**
for database connection am using this

```html
<?php
$user_name="root";
$pass="";
$host="localhost";
$db_name="userdb";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user_name,$pass,$db_name);
if(!$con)
{
 echo "Connection Failed....".mysqli_connect_error();
 
}
else
echo "<h3>Connection Success.....</h3>";

?>
```

**register.php**

```html
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];
require "init.php";
$query="select * from userinfo where email like '".$email."';";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
//ok
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
 $response=array();
 $code="reg_false";
 $message="User already exist....";
 array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
 echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
}
else
{
    $querys ="insert into userinfo values ('".$name."','".$email."','".$pass."');";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$querys);
    if(!$result)
    {
        $response=array();
        $code="reg_false";
        $message="Some server error occurred, Train again....";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
    }else{
        $response=array();
        $code="reg_true";
        $message="Registration Success....Thank you....";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**register_test.html**
this one is used for to send the details to the database, am using this one like as input to send data

```html
<html>
<head> <title>Register Test....</title> </head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email :</td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please check this code, and please tell where i done the mistake to got the pass word values into my database

Comment: Well for one you don't need .$variable. you can just insert them as values '$variable'.   When you echo out $pass before the insert does it come as empty or does it have a value.  Also why aren't you using prepared statements if you're inserting variables ?

Comment: Possibly the most significant mistake is that this code is wide open to SQL injection.  What this means is not only that it's open to malicious code from users, but also that you don't actually know what SQL query you're executing.  Echo the actual runtime SQL query so you can check it.  Additionally, look at `mysqli_error()` when the query fails.

Comment: @clearshot66, i will try wait a minute

Comment: @clearshot66, it's not working bro.  will you please tell me elaborately.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php   and if you echo $pass upon form submit, does it print out the password you entered  at the top of your screen?

Comment: @clearshot66, one thing is sure i dont know about php, and html actually am android developer. i want a sever to check the login and signup response that's why i am here. from last 6 hrs i trying solve this but i am not successes please tell me some code please

Comment: @yuggi  literally type  print_r($_POST); under all your post variables,   then fill in your form and submit, then see if a password variable comes there in that array.

Comment: @sorry for this where in registe.php or register_test.html

Comment: @clearshot66 i got a message like    Array ( [name] => jaggu [password] => jaggu [email] => jaggu24 ), but in data base it not showing the password coloumn

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Also in your error processing get into the habit of outputting the actual database error (while testing) using `mysqli_error($con)` rather than just a user message which does not help you debug your query

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your other two are getting inserted, try this:

```
$querys ="INSERT INTO userinfo (name,email,password) VALUES ('$name','$email','$pass');
$result = $mysqli_query($con,$querys);
```

Comment: Are your other two fields getting entered into your database with the password column blank? What do you mean by NOT working

Comment: yes if gave the pass work is blank, also it's working fine and gives the same result

Comment: But are the other columns blank?

Comment: it requires email column only if it is unique one it executes